# Classification/Probability of Treatment using NeuralNet

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I have 10000 observations. There are 3 variables. The first variable d is binary and takes the values 0 and 1 (this is the treatment assignment). The other 2 variables are x and z, and these are continuous.

I want to use neuralnet in R to predict the probability of being treated.

The command I was using is as follows:

```
nn = neuralnet(d~x+z, data2, hidden = 1, threshold = 0.01, linear.output = TRUE)

h=prediction(nn)

data_nn = h$rep1
```

The idea being that the prediction will give me a variable that contains the probabilities. While this method fits the data, I find that some of the estimated probabilities are greater than 1. I was wondering if this is indeed the correct way to proceed?

Or is there a separate way to specify to the neuralnet command that this is a classification problem (as opposed to regression problem) and the output needs to be the probability of lying in a class?

Comment: I believe you have to use one-hot encoding of your dependent variable, for example if d has three categories, you have to create binary classes of these categories, so it would be sth like d1 + d2 +d3  ~ x + z, also in the function, you should use, linear.output = F and act.fct = 'logistic'. I can't answer it fully as I don't have your dataset. But I can see these are some of the problems, If you fix them, I am hopeful that you will recieve probabilities at your end.

Comment: @PKumar Those adjustments worked. Since d is binary itself, I didn't have to create categories. Do I need to do any cross validation exercise here though? Do you know of any resources that can guide me? My end goal is to get the best possible estimates of the probabilities.

Comment: Here is one: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/creating-visualizing-neural-network-in-r/ and another one: https://www.r-bloggers.com/multilabel-classification-with-neuralnet-package/